# Bridge building with irregular planks

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics

Imagine you have a big rectangular pond in your back garden. You wish to build a bridge from your house in the lower left corner to the small pagoda in the top right.

You have lots of planks of length $1$ and $2$. You only wish to place planks orthogonal to the sides of the pond, and you don't want to go backwards ever. The pond is $10\times10$.

> How many ways are there to do this?

For example:

```
. . . ._P
      |
. . . . .
      |
. . . . .
      |
. . ._. .
    |
H_._. . .
```

> For a bonus, is there a generic solution for planks of length $l_1,l_2,\dots,l_k$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rather than thinking of planks as having lengths, think of them as defining certain sets of *vectors*. So in this case we have (1,0), (0,1), (2,0), (0,2). (Caution: if you have e.g. a plank of length 5 then you need to allow (3,4) and (4,3) as well as (5,0) and (0,5)! [EDITED to add:] No, as pointed out by another user in comments that's wrong because the question specifies orthogonal only. Though obviously you could also do it the other way if you wanted :-).)

Now we have a recurrence relation: if we write $N(a,b)$ for the number of ways to span a pond of size $(a,b)$ then we have $N(0,0)=1$ and $N(a,b)=\sum N(a-x,b-y)$ where the sum is over plank-vectors $(x,y)$.

For the particular case here, the table looks like this:

$$\begin{array}{r}
1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 5 & 8 & 13 & 21 & 34 & 55 & 89 \\
1 & 2 & 5 & 10 & 20 & 38 & 71 & 130 & 235 & 420 & 744 \\
2 & 5 & 14 & 32 & 71 & 149 & 304 & 604 & 1177 & 2256 & 4266 \\
3 & 10 & 32 & 84 & 207 & 478 & 1060 & 2272 & 4744 & 9692 & 19446 \\
5 & 20 & 71 & 207 & 556 & 1390 & 3310 & 7576 & 16807 & 36331 & 76850 \\
8 & 38 & 149 & 478 & 1390 & 3736 & 9496 & 23080 & 54127 & 123230 & 273653 \\
13 & 71 & 304 & 1060 & 3310 & 9496 & 25612 & 65764 & 162310 & 387635 & 900448 \\
21 & 130 & 604 & 2272 & 7576 & 23080 & 65764 & 177688 & 459889 & 1148442 & 2782432 \\
34 & 235 & 1177 & 4744 & 16807 & 54127 & 162310 & 459889 & 1244398 & 3240364 & 8167642 \\
55 & 420 & 2256 & 9692 & 36331 & 123230 & 387635 & 1148442 & 3240364 & 8777612 & 22968050 \\
89 & 744 & 4266 & 19446 & 76850 & 273653 & 900448 & 2782432 & 8167642 & 22968050 & 62271384
\end{array}
$$

The number you want is in the bottom right of the array. This happens to be http://oeis.org/A036355. In general, the generating function for these things is $\frac1{1-\sum x^{dx}y^{dy}}$ where the sum is over plank-vectors $(dx,dy)$. I guess you can probably get a closed form out of that somehow.

Comment: I was about to post the same table. :-)

Comment: Why am I not surprised that the person saying that is you? :-)

Comment: On my computer, the table spills over into the HNQ. Maybe just me?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan The (3,4)/(4,3) bit is wrong, and confused me for a minute before I realized what you meant. You can't place planks on an angle like that, since the question specified that planks must be "orthogonal to the sides of the pond".

Comment: Oh, so it did. Quite true. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Brandon_J Not just you, me too

Answer (score 2):

My answer (using a computer program) is:

> There are **8777612** ways to arrange the planks.
>  I solved this using a C program
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
>
> #define WIDTH   10
> #define DEPTH   10
> #define PLANK   2
>
> unsigned long long cache[DEPTH][WIDTH];
>
> unsigned long long recur(int row, int col) {
>     if(row >= DEPTH || col >= WIDTH)
>         return 0;
>     if(row == DEPTH-1 && col == WIDTH-1)
>         return 1;
>     if(cache[row][col] != 0)
>         return cache[row][col];
>
>     unsigned long long paths = 0;
>     for(int p = 1; p <= PLANK; p++) {
>         paths += recur(row + p, col);
>         paths += recur(row, col + p);
>     }
>     cache[row][col] = paths;
>     return paths;
> }
>
> int main(void) {
>     printf("Paths = %llu\n", recur(0, 0));
> }
> ```

Note that this is from coordinate (0,0) to (9,9) because the start and finish points are *in the pond*. The distance is $9$ in each direction. It checks out when manually counting small ponds.

This also provides a generic solution for ponds up to $26 \times 26$, or up to $2^{64}-1$ paths.
For small ponds the cache isn't necessary.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry isn't the other answer for 11 x 11 pond? Count across the table.